# Number of files in a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to get the number of all files of all commits in a repository on GitHub?
I don't use Git myself, I just need to know the number of some other big repositories.
Let's take for example [JQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

**Update**
There are files like:

- .editorconfig
- .gitattributes
- ...

and of course folder like:

- build
- external
- ...

with even more files.

I need to know the total number of those files.
And, as a bonus, I would like to know the total number of files ever existed in this repository.

Is it possible to find these numbers on GitHub?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to know the number of files that have ever existed in a repository?

Comment: Yes, the current number (which is more important), an if possible the number of all files, every existed.

Comment: @user1170330 Like Chris, I'm trying to make sense of your question... Note that Git doesn't store files in a conventional sense. Are you familiar with the concept of [*blob*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)? Are you asking how many blobs a repository contains?

Comment: @user1170330 *I need to know the total number of those files* So, you want the total number of files in a certain revision. Correct?

Comment: @Jubobs: Yes, this is the more important part. Additionally I would like to know the total number of files ever existed.

Comment: Just to clarify... You write: *I don't use Git myself, I just need to know the number of some other big repositories*. Is using Git even a bit completely out of the question?

Comment: @Jubobs: I'm not experienced with Git. I assume I would have to going through the whole installation process, just to get the total values.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @rubenvb that you're going to have to clone the repo and do the count locally. I don't know a tool which will get the number of files for each revision, so you're going to have to roll your own.

To get the count at the current checked-out commit, you could run `git ls-files | wc -l` which will give you a total for the repo at that commit.

To get the all-time count, you'd need to loop over all the commits reachable from the first commit, running that command each time. You might try pushing the output of `git ls-files` into an array each time, and maintain a "global" array while looping through all commits. (This is likely to take some time on a big repo like jQuery.) Then you can count the size of the array afterward.

The number is going to be pretty subjective depending on what you decide to count, though. Should you count a file which moves from one directory to another in a commit? (In the method I've just outlined, it will be counted as two different files.) Do you count branches which haven't been merged to master, or just any commit reachable from the HEAD of the current master branch? That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do a (shallow) clone of the repository, and count locally?

I am not aware of any github web gui tool that shows you this information.

Also: getting the total number of files that ever existed would be difficult, as many deletions or renames or whatever may or may not count for whatever you need this statistic.